# EF Core tracking child objects unnecessarily

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

**The Problem**

Entity Framework Core v3.1.4

I'm working on some forum software, and want to add a new `Topic` to a `Board`. The Board has tens of thousands of topics, and when I use `board.Topics.Add(topic)`, it's iterating and tracking *all* topics of that board, which is taking forever (e.g., minutes).

```
var board = _commandContext.Boards.Find(boardID);

var topic = new Topic() { 
    BoardID = boardID,
    Board = board
    Title = ...
    ...
};

// takes minutes, tracks all topics in the Board instance
board.Topics.Add(topic);
```

... in the above code, when I hit the `board.Topics.Add(topic)` line, the debugger spits out one of these for each topic in the board (which is tens of thousands...):

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking: Debug: Context 'CommandDataContext' started tracking 'Topic' entity. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see key values.

**The Question**

Why is EF deciding it needs to track all board topics when I run `_commandContext.Topics.Add(topic);`?  I make subsequent calls to things like `board.GetLatestTopic()`, which I fully expect it to execute a query for, but a) that shouldn't have to track all topics, and b) this tracking happens prior to any other calls.

This seems unnecessary and I don't recall it being a particular issue in EF6.

**Alternate Method**

If I add the entity using this method:

```
_commandContext.Topics.Add(topic);
```

... the process if fast (all board topics are not tracked), but then subsequent calls to things like `board.GetLatestTopic()` don't work because that topic wasn't tracked.

**Entities and EF Config**

My `Board` and `Topic` entities are straightforward, nothing I haven't done in dozens of other projects:

```
public class Board
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public BoardStatus Status { get; set; } = BoardStatus.Inactive;
    public BoardType Type { get; set; } = BoardType.Standard;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    ...
    
    public virtual ICollection<Topic> Topics { get; set; } = new List<Topic>();

    public Topic LatestTopic {
        get {
            return this.Topics.Where(x => x.IsStandard).OrderByDescending(x => x.DateStartedUTC).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

My EF configuration is also straightforward:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(_loggerFactory);
        optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }
}
...
modelBuilder.Entity<Board>(e => {
    e.ToTable("Boards", "forum");
    e.HasOne(x => x.Category)
        .WithMany(x => x.Boards)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.CategoryID);
    e.HasMany(x => x.Topics)
        .WithOne(x => x.Board)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.BoardID);
});
```

Comment: You've got a bug somewhere.  Something involving your LatestTopic property and lazy loading.  Try to boil the behavior down to a repro you can add to your question.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - I removed all property shortcuts such as LatestTopic, and the behavior is still present.  Please note also that this happens when calling `board.Topics.Add(topic);` regardless of I call any subsequent properties on the object.  My domain models are now straight POCOs and my EF configuration is as shown... it's a simple isolated service and not much to it other than what I've described already, but the behavior is still present.

Comment: I copied what I could see from the question and the behavior didn't repro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Saving Related Data: Adding a graph of new entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data):

> If you create several new related entities, adding one of them to the context will cause the others to be added too.

So this is the default behavior and is the way the `Add()` and `AddRange()` (and other) methods are implemented.

However, you can just set the entity's state by yourself, or even override how EF Core tracks entire graphs (for the latter one, see [Disconnected entities: TrackGraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#trackgraph)):

```cs
_commandContext.Entry(topic).State = EntityState.Added;
```

This just adds the `topic` object without related entities.

---

Here is a simple but fully working sample console project, that demonstrates this:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class IceCream
    {
        public int IceCreamId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int IceCreamShopId { get; set; }

        public IceCreamShop IceCreamShop { get; set; }
    }

    public class IceCreamShop
    {
        public int IceCreamShopId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public virtual ICollection<IceCream> IceCreams { get; set; } = new HashSet<IceCream>();
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<IceCream> IceCreams { get; set; }
        public DbSet<IceCreamShop> IceCreamShops { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=.\MSSQL14;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=So63094891")
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            AddShopWithIceCreams();
            CheckIceCreams(2);
            
            AddShopWithoutIceCreams();
            CheckIceCreams(0);
        }

        private static void AddShopWithIceCreams()
        {
            using var context = new Context();

            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var newShop = new IceCreamShop
            {
                Name = "My Shop",
                IceCreams =
                {
                    new IceCream {Name = "Vanilla", IceCreamShopId = 1},
                    new IceCream {Name = "Chocolate", IceCreamShopId = 1},
                }
            };

            context.IceCreamShops.Add(newShop);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        private static void AddShopWithoutIceCreams()
        {
            using var context = new Context();

            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var newShop = new IceCreamShop
            {
                Name = "My Shop",
                IceCreams =
                {
                    new IceCream {Name = "Vanilla", IceCreamShopId = 1},
                    new IceCream {Name = "Chocolate", IceCreamShopId = 1},
                }
            };

            context.Entry(newShop).State = EntityState.Added;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public static void CheckIceCreams(int iceCreamCount)
        {
            using var context = new Context();
            
            var shops = context.IceCreamShops
                .Include(s => s.IceCreams)
                .ToList();

            Debug.Assert(shops.Count == 1);
            Debug.Assert(shops[0].IceCreams.Count == iceCreamCount);
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### How change tracking traversal works

Since this came up in the comments, here is an except from the internal [ChangeTracker.TrackGraph()](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/59734ea22f29d22f8d0c1673c59a99c54ec4e78d/src/EFCore/ChangeTracking/ChangeTracker.cs#L261) method's description summary, that sums up pretty well how the change tracking traversal works:

> Begins tracking an entity and any entities that are reachable by traversing it's navigation properties.
>
> Traversal is recursive so the navigation properties of any discovered entities will also be scanned.
>
> [...]
>
> If an entity is discovered that is already tracked by the context, that entity is not processed (and it's navigation properties are not traversed).

Comment: I don't think this is quite what I'm asking: _If you create several new related entities, adding one of them to the context will cause the others to be added too_ - understood, yes, and expected, but that's not what I'm doing.  I'm adding a single entity, but it's loading and tracking the entire parent entity's graph.  It's loading the full graph of the parent even tho I'm adding only a single child entity.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is what happens in your case. You add a single `Topic` that EF Core then tracks. EF Core then uses its `GraphTracker` to walk along all navigation properties of this `Topic`. That includes the `Topic.Board` navigation property. So EF Core starts tracking the `Board` as well. On the `Board`, it then walks along all _its_ navigation properties, including the `Board.Topics` collection. It then resolves every single `Topic` from that collection and starts tracking them, and so on. The sample code I posted demonstrates this behavior.

Comment: Also take a look at the [TrackGraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#trackgraph) link I referenced. There it states: _"Internally, Add, Attach, and Update use graph-traversal with a determination made for each entity as to whether it should be marked as Added (to insert), Modified (to update), Unchanged (do nothing), or Deleted (to delete)."_ For EF Core, adding an entity is just changing its tracking state. And all navigation properties will be traversed and tracked as well, if you use the usual methods like `Add()` or `AddRange()`.

Comment: Hmm, seems by that logic any referenced entity would always have a deep-resolution tracking of all related entities (which, in many cases, could mean almost the entire database!), which is the opposite of what I'd expect.  I'll sit on it a bit more and see if I can make sense of it, but it's not clicking in my head yet.  Appreciate the effort to help...

Comment: Just replace your `_commandContext.Topics.Add(topic);` line with `_commandContext.Entry(topic).State = EntityState.Added;`. It should work immediately as you want it to. Also, the sample code I posted is complete, so you can just copy it and step through it with a debugger.

Comment: I updated my answer with a short section about how the change tracking traversal works. It references the source code and quotes the official `TrackGraph()` method description.

Comment: You're right.  I still don't quite understand, but it works.  I'll study on it more, but I'm past the block for the moment, thanks